# SSL: CERTIFICATE FAILED

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, request

I have been trying to send a GET Request to a web but I've been raised following Error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='courses.fit.hcmus.edu.vn', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /course/view.php?id=2040 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))
```

This is my code up to now:

```
import requests
session = requests.get('https://courses.fit.hcmus.edu.vn/course/view.php?id=2040')

print(session.text)
```

This web requires account and password but I've tried to use cookies already but I got same errors,...
I've try to upgrade pip or several things familiar to that but it didn't work.

Thanks,
Tien Dung